# Does this cause memory leak and how do I stop it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I use a UIViewController XIB to create my UITableViewCell in IB then I implemented it in code like this:

```
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TotalViewCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = (TotalViewCell *)viewController.view;
        //[viewController release];
    }
    [[cell totalButton] setTitle:@"$100,000" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Action when totalButton is tapped
    [[cell totalButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(showTotalDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
```

Usually, I would release the viewController but I put a UIButton inside that cell and when the user taps the button, showTotalDetail gets called. This is the code for showTotalDetail:

```
-(void)showTotalDetail:(id)sender
{
    // Move the totalTableView up!
    CGRect totalDetailTableViewFrame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 280, 200);
    [totalTableView setFrame:totalDetailTableViewFrame];

    // Reload the new totalTableView
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

The function basically resizes the tableView and moves it to a different location on the screen. So, if I release the viewController, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. It works if I don't release but I'm afraid I will have memory leaks.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You’re creating a `UIViewController` for each `UITableViewCell`? That’s pretty non-standard behavior. If you need to customize the behavior of a `UITableViewCell`, it’s probably better to subclass it than to use a view controller.

If you need to load a table view cell from a nib, look at Apple’s [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/). That example is in there without using a view controller.

As to your question: you’re right that in this scenario, the `UIViewController` will leak.

Comment: Yea. I follow the guide from here: http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/

Comment: I can’t recommend that blog’s advice.